# Accept a websocket upgrade from an MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, model-view-controller, websocket, port

Is it possible to have my client request a websocket connection to an MVC controller named `"socket"` for example (`"ws://mysite.com/socket"`)? If so, how do I accept the upgrade request and handle the communication from within the `"socket"` controller?

If not, how else can I integrate a websocket into my MVC app? The MVC app will be acting server-side and the client side is handled by an API.

Comment: I haven't done this myself but AFAIK I don't think you use conventional controllers for websockets - it's not a regular HTTP request. I suggest you look into SignalR and maybe find some tutorials / documentation. It's too broad a topic for a quick answer here.

Comment: I am hosting my MVC app on a Google Compute Engine virtual machine, and I was hoping that I would be able to open a web socket within the MVC app. Otherwise, I’d have to create a whole new server just so I can open a web socket.

Comment: Again, look it up, but AFAIK you can integrate websockets into an MVC app (e.g. by using a package such as SignalR), I was just pointing out that it doesn't expose the endpoint in the form of a controller. I think you just need to do some research and try it out, TBH. I can't really see why you'd need a whole new server, but maybe I'm wrong. Sorry I can't be of more help than that, but I strongly suspect that most or all of what you need to know is already out there if you go looking.

Comment: I was lead to believe that I cannot use SignalR because my client is not simply a browser etc., it is handled by an API.

Comment: What makes you think that? A quick google reveals many links including. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003674/5947043. SignalR is just a neat packaged way of implementing websockets in a .NET server. The underlying technology is still the same - websockets. Just like with HTTP, once you've exposed an endpoint it doesn't matter how it was implemented, the client never sees that. The protocol to talk to it is just the same. That's the beauty of the web, any machine which knows the protocol can talk to any other, regardless of the O/S or programming languages at either end of the line.